# Simplify appears to give different results

Tags: simplifying-expressions, numerical-value

I have an issue with Simplify (and FullSimplify) giving a different numerical expression to the pre-Simplified expression. The function is an alternating sum of trigonometric quantities:

```
f[n_, x_] := Sum[Sum[(-1)^j Sin[(j-1)(n-2)Pi/n], {j, x, i-1}] * 
    Sum[(-1)^j Sin[(j-1)(n-2)Pi/n], {j, 2, i}], {i, 2, n-1}]
```

If I evaluate this at $(n, x) = (6, 3)$ for instance, my answer is 2.25. But if I first pass this expression to Simplify, e.g.

```
g[n_, x_] := Simplify[f[n, x]]
```

then evaluate, my answer is 1.5.

Which answer should I trust and what's the source of the issue? I should add that I'm using an older version of Mathematica (10.3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that what you're seeing is a bug. The problem is that `Sum` implicitly assumes that the summation bounds are ordered and differ by an integer amount (mentioned [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html#442779753)). The following example illustrates how this might cause issues:

```
(* evaluate sum symbolically *)
Sum[i, {i, a, b}]
(* -(1/2) (-1 + a - b) (a + b) *)

(* insert problematic values with a>b into symbolic result *)
Sum[i, {i, a, b}] /. {a -> 4, b -> 2}
(* -3 *)

(* insert values before evaluating *)
Unevaluated@Sum[i, {i, a, b}] /. {a -> 4, b -> 2}
(* 0 *)

(* generate conditions to verify input *)
Sum[i, {i, a, b}, GenerateConditions -> True] /. {a -> 4, 
  b -> 2}
(* Undefined *)
```

As you can see (and as noted in the documentation page linked above), [`GenerateConditions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GenerateConditions.html) can be used to protect against this problem. Note however that the result will simply be `Undefined` in those cases instead of `0`.

Now, how does this apply to the example in the question? The issue lies in the first inner sum:

```
Sum[(-1)^j Sin[(j-1)(n-2)Pi/n], {j, x, i-1}]
```

For $i=6,x=3$, we are in the case where the lower bound is larger than the upper bound, so symbolic evaluation will produce incorrect results. Adding `GenerateConditions->True` tells us that something is indeed wrong:

```
f[n_, x_] = Sum[
  Sum[
    (-1)^j Sin[(j - 1) (n - 2) Pi/n],
    {j, x, i - 1},
    GenerateConditions -> True
    ]*Sum[
    (-1)^j Sin[(j - 1) (n - 2) Pi/n],
    {j, 2, i},
    GenerateConditions -> True
    ],
  {i, 2, n - 1},
  GenerateConditions -> True
  ];

f[6, 3]
(* Undefined *)
```

In summary, be careful with sums with symbolic bounds, and check whether the lower bound is less than the upper one. Unless there really is a bug somewhere, the correct result should be `9/4`, since there, the sums are done with the explicit values instead of symbolically.

Comment: Thanks - do you happen to know if Mathematica is able to handle (in Simplify) empty summations, for instance through another function? Or should I always ensure that the sum is never empty to avoid such problems?

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce the first part you say. On `V 12` on windows 10, I get 2.25 in both cases (it has to be, as simplifying 2.25 to 1.5 would be a really bad bug)

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But what I see, is that when changing the definition from delayed `:=` to `=`, then now Mathematica gives `1.5`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And this I think must be a bug.

---

Code

```
ClearAll[n, x, j, i, f, g];
f[n_, x_] := 
  Sum[Sum[(-1)^j Sin[(j - 1) (n - 2) Pi/n], {j, x, i - 1}]*
    Sum[(-1)^j Sin[(j - 1) (n - 2) Pi/n], {j, 2, i}], {i, 2, n - 1}];
f[6, 3]
(* 9/4 *)
```

And now (this will take few seconds, since it is immediate evaluation)

```
ClearAll[n, x, j, i, f, g];
f[n_, x_] = 
  Sum[Sum[(-1)^j Sin[(j - 1) (n - 2) Pi/n], {j, x, i - 1}]*
    Sum[(-1)^j Sin[(j - 1) (n - 2) Pi/n], {j, 2, i}], {i, 2, n - 1}];
f[6, 3]
(* 3/2 *)
```

btw, the same issue shows up on `11.3` as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help - do you know which expression is correct / more reliable? I suppose I should probably do a computation myself but I don't really trust myself... in any event, I should add that following your tests, I get a different answer if I do:

g[n_, x_] := Simplify[f[n,x]]

which gives me g[6, 3] = 9/4, but if I do Simplify[f[n,x]] then copy the input from the console and paste it into g[n_, x_] := (Ctrl+V), then I get 3/2. Is this also a bug I'm guessing?

Comment: In Maple `sum` gives 3/2 and `add` gives 9/4.